# SharePoint Custom List Search Problem

Tags: 2010, list, search

I have a created a SharePoint custom list so it can be used as a customer "data base".

The problem I'm facing is when some one perform a search, the site does not show any results despite the information is in the list.

I mean if I perform a search for my customer `ABC`  or the customer number `1234` no records are found, but when you go to the list the information is there.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the list contents are enabled for searching. Go to List Settings --> Advanced Settings and see if

> Allow items from this list to appear in search results?

is marked as "Yes".

Also, make sure that Search Service Application in Central Admin is crawling your content.

Comment: Thank you so much Ransher... the list contents are enable for searching, but I keep getting the same problem

Comment: Are contents from the other lists on your site showing up in search results?